# Use binance-api-node with reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, binance

Hello everyone I can't use the binance-api-node module in react. The goal is to retrieve the data of an account but when I import the module here is my error that I do not understand

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyLXd.png)

Comment: The clue is in the name of the package. It's a _node_ module, and can't be used in React.

Comment: It is really impossible ?

Comment: It is really impossible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.